# How can I check to see if elements of a 2D array are null in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a 2d arrays centroids which each of its elements is an array itself. How can I check to see if say `centroids[1][1]` list contains any element?

I thought this code would work but it is not.

```
 for (int j=0; j<centroids[clusterAssignment[i]].length;j++)
        if(centroids[clusterAssignment[i]].length==0)
```

firstly because `centroids[clusterAssignment[i]].length` doesn't give me the correct list of number of centroids and just tell me that it is 2 because centroids have dimension x and y (2d).
Secondly because I don't know how to check if the `clusterAssignment[i]` which is an array has a length of zero or not for centroids i in the list of all the available centroids.

UPDATE: This code doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < centroids.length; i++){
                    //System.out.println("centroids[clusterAssignment[i]] "+ Arrays.toString(centroids[clusterAssignment[i]]));
                    //System.out.println("clusterassignment of centroid is"+centroids[clusterAssignment[i]]);
                    for (int j=0; j<centroids[clusterAssignment[i]].length;j++)
                    //  System.out.println("cluster assignment of centroid is: "+Arrays.toString(centroids[clusterAssignment[i]]));
                    if (centroids[clusterAssignment[i]] == null){
                        //save the centroid number if there's no point assigned to it
                        orphanCentroid = i;
                        System.out.println("orphan centroid i is "+i);
                        hasOrphanCentroid=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `centroids[clusterAssignment[i]] == null`

Comment: It is not working. Because centroids length is always 2. It doesn't look into the inner array!

Comment: What is the type of `centroids`? Also, what does clusterAssignment represent?

Comment: I have to use centroids[clusterAssignment[i]] where in clusterAssignment is `int[] clusterAssignment = new int[instances.length];` and `double[][] instances` .

Comment: @Multithreader basically centroids are points in 2d dimension.

Comment: @MonaJalal so a centroid is something like (+3,-6) ? which is a point in an x,y plane?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int j=0; j<centroids[clusterAssignment[i]].length;j++)
        if(centroids[clusterAssignment[i]]==null)
```